# Detect zooming on the Samsung S7 (nougat)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-7.0-nougat, google-vr

I have a Google VR based application which had some very strange scaling issue on the Samsung S7.

I don't have the device at hand (that would be too easy...) but, with the help of the affected user, we tracked down the issue to the scaling feature that the new Nougat firmware applies by default to the device, reducing the resolution from WQHD to Full HD.

Is there a way to detect whether the down-scaling is activated? What classes are affected?

Thanks!